# ajax json php not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a script that will post a comment. All works but i need it so if there are any errors found with php, it will alert the user the error, else it will show the comment

here is the ajax part

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'comment/post.php',
        data: ajaxData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(result){

              if(result.error == true){
                   alert(result.error);
              } else {
                   $('#comments').prepend(result.comment);
              }
        }
});
```

and the php (note this is only part, but you should understand). So if there is an error it should alert, else the comment should come through. But its not working

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){

        $image_key = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
        $new_image_name = $image_key.'.jpg';

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../uploads/'.$new_image_name);
        $file = '<img src="uploads/'.$new_image_name.'" />';

        $Comment->addImage($new_image_name, $random);

        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'Your file was too big'));

    } 

    echo json_encode(array('comment' => 'Here is your comment blah blah'));

    header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: Use the echo once...bind both the array together...like a json object thrn encode and return

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see with what you've posted is that you have to set the header BEFORE you output anything. So in your PHP file, move the `header('Content-type: application/json');` to the top of your file or at least above any output. Otherwise, the content-type header won't get set.

From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

`Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.`

Another problem is that you are outputting two separate json_encoded arrays when the request is successful. You should only have one (which can contain multiple arrays inside), so adjust your code as follows:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    ...

    echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'Your file was too big'));
                                            ^-- Are you missing an array index here for your comment?
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('comment' => 'Here is your comment blah blah'));
}
```

As noted in my code block, it looks like your first array is possibly missing an index. Did you forget to include 'comment' (ie `'comment' => 'Your file was too big'`)?

Also, to make your AJAX call a little more robust, you can add `.done()` and `.fail()` methods. Example:

```
$.post( "example.php", function() {
// your AJAX configuration
})
.done(function(data) {
// AJAX call succeeded, do something like process the data sent back
})
.fail(function(error, status, jqXHR) {
// AJAX call failed, do something like alert the user
});
```

Read the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for AJAX calls.

Answer (score -1):

First remove the header in php files, second your php is returning 2 array it should not

Comment: it needs to be 2 arrays tho, doesn't it?

Comment: No there shloud only be one array returned